# multiple regex match using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var wordsString="car/home/pencil,Joe/Hugh/Jack/Chris";
var word='home';
var pattern1=/^/+word;
var pattern2=/,/+word;
var pattern3 =/\//+word;

var matched = wordsString.match(pattern1+ /|/ +pattern2+ /|/ + pattern3 + /g/);
```

I want to match results from `wordsString` by using `pattern1`, `pattern2`, `pattern3`.

I need to match according to `pattern1` or `pattern2` or `pattern3`. But I get `null`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You can't concatenate regex

Comment: Don't attempt to use the value of a variable until it has been assigned. And regex literals don't work like this.

Comment: convert your string to a RegExp object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589587/javascript-regular-expression-string-to-regex-object

Comment: Are you just trying to match "home"? Whats wrong with `/home/`? is it that you want to use a variable to make the regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate regexp literals. However, you can concatenate strings and use them to build a regexp object:

```
var wordsString = "car/home/pencil,Joe/Hugh/Jack/Chris",
    word = 'home',
    escapedWord = RegExp.escape(word),
    patterns = ['^' + escapedWord, ',' + escapedWord, '/' + escapedWord],
    regex = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'g'),
    matched = wordsString.match(regex);
```

`RegExp.escape` is needed in case `word` contains characters with special meaning in regular expressions. It has been proposed as a standard but has not been accepted yet, so you must define it manually using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1529630).

Comment: I also a need pattern to catch "car/home/" or Joe/Hugh/...I mean I also need to catch 2 "/" with 2 words. How can I define it like "/" repeated 2 times and then get the words together.

Comment: `word = 'Joe/Hugh'`?

Comment: well to be specific, when dynamic "word" catches Chris then how can I get Joe/Hugh/ with regex  automatically afterwards ...

Comment: Consider not using regex: `var wordsString = "car/home/pencil,Joe/Hugh/Jack/Chris", word = 'home', matched = wordsString.split(',').filter(function(str){ return str.split('/').indexOf(word) >= 0; });`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate Regex's in JavaScript the way you are doing it, but you can concat strings that comprise a single regex.  Don't escape the pipe symbol though, that is how it matches this or that.

```
var one = "test"
var two = "this"

var regex = new RegExp("^(first|" + one + "|" + two + ")")

var match = regex.test("this"); // matches
var noMatch = regex.test("no match"); // does not match
```