# Matching the string "/$" in a RegExp constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the phrase "/$" using the `RegExp` constructor, but no amount of escaping seems to help. Am is missing something?

```
RegExp("\/\$").test("/$")
// false
RegExp("/$").test("/$")
// false
RegExp("\/$").test("/$")
// false
RegExp("/\$").test("/$")
// false
```

Comment: `RegExp("\\$").test("$")`

Comment: `RegExp("\\/\\$").test("/$")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\\` instead of `\` and there is no need to escape `/` or use regex `/\/\$/` directly. Check [`RegExp` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) for more info.

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.

For example,   `/\w+/` is equivalent to `new RegExp('\\w+')`

```js
console.log(
  RegExp("/\\$").test("/$")
)

//or

console.log(
  /\/\$/.test("/$")
)
```

Refer : [Javascript regular expression - string to RegEx object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589587/javascript-regular-expression-string-to-regex-object)