# Does regex syntax provide a way of escaping a whole string, rather than escaping characters one by one?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I want to find a reference to precisely the following string:

```
http ://www.mydomain.com/home
```

within a more complex regex expression.
Is it possible to escape the **whole sequence** instead of escaping each / and . character **individually**? To get something **more readable** than

```
/http:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/home/
```

In the regex parsing site https://regexr.com/ , if I type the url in and set a regex to

```
/(http ://www.mydomain.com/home)/
```

, it *appears* to recognize the string, yet declares an error:

```
Unescaped forward slash. This may cause issues if copying/pasting this expression into code.
```

So I'm confused about this issue.

Comment: You want to have a multiline regex expression? Or am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp, you can match multiple lines using: `myString.match(/.*/, 'm')`

Comment: What backslashes have you got and which ones do you want to get rid of? What does regex have to do with this?

Comment: @TheChetan You wanted to write `myString.match(/.+/g)` I believe. [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Syntax) only accepts a single argument, a RegExp object.

Comment: edited the question, as it appears not to have been understood.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't really do this in JS. In Java and Perl, you can use the `\Q` and `\E` metacharacters. However, you can't really do that in JS (https://stackoverflow.com/q/6318710/4851565). However, there is this nifty answer on escaping regexes in JS (https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446170/4851565).

Comment: thanks @entpnerd, that answers the question

Comment: To all: I believe negative votes are due to misunderstanding of the question, that led to being characterized as unsomething (unappropriate? unethical? I forget). The anathema has been lifted since, but the negative votes remain. Oh well.

Comment: @Francis I found this question in the closed queue. The consensus was that the question was unclear. However, based on your edit, it was made more clear and was reopened.

Comment: Please someone reclose as a duplicate of [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript). BTW, if it is not about escaping special chars it is no any clearer than it was before reopening.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript, unless I misunderstood. What I understand of that post is that he wants to take a string and transform that into a regex expression. What I want to do is to prevent regex from parsing one part of the expression.

Comment: Investigating further, this question seems to give the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: I had trouble reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript because it concentrates on the how rather than the what

Comment: What I was looking for was a simpler solution, one that would use regex syntax, that would not oblige me to concatenate a string, then create a new regex object. It appears that doesn't exist. I don't understand the issue people have with the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that regex does not offer such a syntax, at least for Javascript. It is possible, however, to proceed as follows:

1. use a string and automatically escape all the special characters in it,
   as indicated here: [Javascript regular expression - string to RegEx object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589587/javascript-regular-expression-string-to-regex-object)
2. concatenate that string with strings representing the rest of the expression you want to create
3. transform the string into a regex expression as indicated in [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) .